# why lable's text can't change, but can debug str?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

why lable's  text can't change, but can debug str?
i know  queue.sync is excute in main thread，when i sleep  in  main  thread。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", qos: .userInteractive)
    let sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            queue.sync {
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
                let str = String(Int.random(in: 1...10))
                debugPrint(str)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.label.text = str
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the incorrect use of `sync`. That blocks the calling thread (i.e., the main thread, in this case). We never block the main thread.

Comment: If you want it to do something every two seconds, instead of a `for` loop with `sleep`, one would generally use a repeating `Timer` or a GCD timer. With `async`-`await` found in Swift concurrency, you could use this `for` loop pattern (with `Task.sleep`, not `Thread.sleep`), but this `Thread.sleep` with `for` loop is an anti-pattern in the old GCD world.

Comment: I don't know what the intent was for that unused semaphore, but it's a red flag. Semaphores are generally inefficient, and often introduce deadlock risks. There are almost always better patterns available. Avoid semaphores if you can.

Comment: So, when you retire the `for` loop, and eliminate `sleep`, you end up with something like https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/f769086620f10d9319f67e282429e8d3.

Answer (score 3):

You are blocking yourself. Consider:

```
queue.sync { // 1
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // 2
         // *
    }
}
```

1. You say `queue.sync` while on the main thread. So now the main thread is blocking waiting for `queue` to finish; no code can run on the main thread.
2. You then say `DispatchQueue.main.async`, asking for the closure (`*`) to be performed on the main thread. But that, as we have just said, is impossible; the main thread is blocking, and no code can run on it.

As for your debugPrint, it is on `queue`, not the main thread, so no problem.

<sub>(Note: everything you're doing is illegal. Never block the main thread, and never sleep.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

you are blocking with waiting the main thread for queue to finish the task. So updating label text code not running on main thread. That's by its not updating.

**Try with async method that will not block the main thread.**

```
queue.async {
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
                let str = String(Int.random(in: 1...10))
                debugPrint(str)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.label.text = str
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is correct. But it should be noted that it will not result in the UX that the OP was obviously going for, namely a `for` loop that updates the label once every two seconds.